# Shell script: Surround variable with quotes when passing into an array?

Tags: shell, sh, rake-task

I have a shell script where part of it does this:

```
bundle exec rake parallel[${@:3}];
```

${@:3} is dynamic and could be something like -p thread11 THREAD=test_thread11, or just @test.feature

The rake task is expecting one argument but no matter what I try I can't get the shell script to surround the variable with quotes so instead of sending something like

> bundle exec rake parallel["-p thread11 THREAD=test_thread11"]

I end up sending

> bundle exec rake parallel[-p thread11 THREAD=test_thread11]

Which causes the rake task to fail.

With an echo statement I can get the correct output by doing

> echo "Will use run command" bundle exec rake parallel["'${@:3}'"]

Is it possible to surround the value of the variable with quotes when passing it to the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to use `"${*:3}"` instead, which will produces a single space-delimited word from the 3 arguments rather than a series of individuals words, one per argument.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be it, can you tell me what that notation is called? I'm new to shell scripting so I'll read up on that.

Comment: `@` and `*` are two different *special parameters* (search for that term in the man page). `$*` behaves more "normally", while `$@` has special behavior when quoted (and thus should never be used unquoted and rarely in a larger quoted string).